# hoverable area covers more than just the text of <span> within an <a>?

Tags: html, css

there seems to be a rectangular border which also counts as a hoverable area. I want only the characters to be hoverable. I tried using a span to fix this but it had no effect.

```css
a:hover{
    color: #ff0000;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #ff0000;
}
#shrine{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'aurora';
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ff0000, 1px -1px 0px #ff0000, -1px -1px 0 #ff0000, -1px 1px 0px #ff0000;
    transform: scaleY(1.6) scaleX(.9);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 8vw;
    margin-bottom: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class='maindiv'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href=''><span id='shrine'>SHRINE</span></a>
      </li>
    <ul>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `transform` property changing how the element is being rendered.

When you transform an inline element, its outline will still reference its initial position.

See the examples in the snippet provided. As you transform, the outline of the element will attempt use both the transformed and original bounding box to trigger events.
If you are purely looking to increase the size of the text, I'd suggest using `font-size`

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}

a:hover{
    color: #ff0000;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #ff0000;
}

#shrine,
#shrineSmaller,
#shrineNoTransform,
#shrineRight {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'aurora';
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ff0000, 1px -1px 0px #ff0000, -1px -1px 0 #ff0000, -1px 1px 0px #ff0000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 8vw;
    margin-bottom: 2vw;
}

#shrine {
    transform: scaleY(1.6) scaleX(.9);
}

#shrineSmaller {
    transform: scaleY(1.6) scaleX(.5);
}

#shrineRight {
    transform: scaleY(1.6) scaleX(.9) translateX(115%);
}
```

```html
<div class='maindiv'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href=''><span id='shrine'>SHRINE</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=''><span id='shrineSmaller'>SHRINE</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=''><span id='shrineNoTransform'>SHRINE</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=''><span id='shrineRight'>SHRINE</span></a>
        </li>
    <ul>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SVG path to make only the text hoverable.

- First, go to https://danmarshall.github.io/google-font-to-svg-path/ and generate an SVG path.
- Second, replace `<a href=''><span id='shrine'>SHRINE</span></a>` with the generated SVG path code.
- Third, apply CSS hover styling to the path.

```css
.maindiv svg > g > path:hover {
    fill: red;
    stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='maindiv'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <svg width="255.8" height="70" viewBox="0 0 255.8 70" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.25mm" fill="none" style="stroke:#000;stroke-width:0.25mm;fill:none"><path d="M 195.1 68.1 L 195.1 70 L 160.9 70 L 160.9 68.1 L 167.5 68.1 L 152.6 41.7 L 136.7 68.1 L 147.3 68.1 L 147.3 70 L 126.6 70 L 126.6 68.1 L 133.3 68.1 L 150.8 38.7 L 129.9 2 L 124.5 2 L 124.5 0 L 158.2 0 L 158.2 2 L 151.4 2 L 164.9 26.2 L 180 2 L 169.6 2 L 169.6 0 L 190.1 0 L 190.1 2 L 183.5 2 L 166.6 29 L 189.3 68.1 L 195.1 68.1 Z M 66.8 2.2 L 66.8 0 L 118.8 0 L 119.8 19.8 L 118 19.8 A 67.919 67.919 0 0 0 115.61 14.629 Q 112.508 8.647 109.2 5.95 A 14.803 14.803 0 0 0 104.453 3.42 Q 100.776 2.2 95.7 2.2 L 92.2 2.2 L 92.2 33.1 L 95.6 33.1 A 10.151 10.151 0 0 0 103.094 29.98 A 12.683 12.683 0 0 0 103.5 29.55 A 17.096 17.096 0 0 0 106.329 25.162 Q 107.216 23.219 107.796 20.88 A 30.604 30.604 0 0 0 108 20 L 109.5 20 L 109.5 49.6 L 107.8 49.6 A 43.088 43.088 0 0 0 106.689 45.721 Q 105.372 41.871 103.587 39.632 A 10.977 10.977 0 0 0 102.95 38.9 A 10.075 10.075 0 0 0 97.44 35.96 A 14.764 14.764 0 0 0 94.6 35.7 L 92.2 35.7 L 92.2 67.8 L 96 67.8 A 25.565 25.565 0 0 0 104.39 66.468 A 22.33 22.33 0 0 0 111.65 62.3 Q 118.1 56.8 120.5 48.2 L 122.5 48.2 L 121.7 70 L 66.8 70 L 66.8 67.8 L 72.7 67.8 L 72.7 2.2 L 66.8 2.2 Z M 1 0 L 60 0 L 61 25.1 L 59.1 25.1 Q 54.709 11.827 51.314 6.97 A 17.41 17.41 0 0 0 51.3 6.95 A 10.911 10.911 0 0 0 43.334 2.207 A 15.276 15.276 0 0 0 41.5 2.1 L 40.3 2.1 L 40.3 67.9 L 48.8 67.9 L 48.8 70 L 12.3 70 L 12.3 67.9 L 20.8 67.9 L 20.8 2.1 L 19.5 2.1 A 12.906 12.906 0 0 0 14.943 2.871 Q 11.833 4.035 9.734 6.959 A 14.19 14.19 0 0 0 9.6 7.15 A 29.46 29.46 0 0 0 7.691 10.387 Q 5.851 13.948 3.837 19.465 A 169.507 169.507 0 0 0 1.9 25.1 L 0 25.1 L 1 0 Z M 195.8 0 L 254.8 0 L 255.8 25.1 L 253.9 25.1 Q 249.509 11.827 246.114 6.97 A 17.41 17.41 0 0 0 246.1 6.95 A 10.911 10.911 0 0 0 238.134 2.207 A 15.276 15.276 0 0 0 236.3 2.1 L 235.1 2.1 L 235.1 67.9 L 243.6 67.9 L 243.6 70 L 207.1 70 L 207.1 67.9 L 215.6 67.9 L 215.6 2.1 L 214.3 2.1 A 12.906 12.906 0 0 0 209.743 2.871 Q 206.633 4.035 204.534 6.959 A 14.19 14.19 0 0 0 204.4 7.15 A 29.46 29.46 0 0 0 202.491 10.387 Q 200.651 13.948 198.637 19.465 A 169.507 169.507 0 0 0 196.7 25.1 L 194.8 25.1 L 195.8 0 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></g></svg>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The scaling you're doing is increasing the text's height beyond the line-height of the `li` that contains it. If you set `li{overflow:hidden}`, you can see how much of the text height the `li` considers overflow.

For example, I can add `li {line-height: 350%; overflow:hidden}` to your CSS to make the line-height be the exact size of the text (on my browser) to give a tighter hover perimeter. However, I don't recommend this; I'm just trying to show you what's happening.

```css
a:hover{
    color: #ff0000;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #ff0000;

}
#shrine{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'aurora';
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ff0000, 1px -1px 0px #ff0000, -1px -1px 0 #ff0000, -1px 1px 0px #ff0000;
    transform: scaleY(1.6) scaleX(.9);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 8vw;
    margin-bottom: 2vw;
    
}
li {line-height: 350%; overflow:hidden}
```

```html
<div class='maindiv'>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href=''><span id='shrine'>SHRINE</span></a>
                </li>
            <ul>
<div>
```